# Protocol does not responds to selector

Tags: ios, objective-c-protocol

I have a problem with Objective-C protocols.

I have defined protocol:

```
@protocol PlayerProfileSectionProReviewDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)didReceivedPlayerProfileSectionProReviewData;

@end

@interface PlayerProfileSectionProReviewModel : PlayerProfileSectionModel

@property (weak) id <PlayerProfileSectionProReviewDelegate> playerProfileSectionProReviewDelegate;

@end
```

In this class implementation I call delegate:

```
if ([self.playerProfileSectionProReviewDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didReceivedPlayerProfileSectionProReviewData)])
{
    [self.playerProfileSectionProReviewDelegate didReceivedPlayerProfileSectionProReviewData];
}
```

In view controller I have added `PlayerProfileSectionProReviewDelegate` and overriden `didReceivedPlayerProfileSectionProReviewData` method:

```
@interface PlayerProfileSectionProReviewViewController : PlayerProfileSectionViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, PlayerProfileSectionProReviewDelegate>

@end
```

and

```
#pragma mark <PlayerProfileSectionProReviewDelegate>

- (void)didReceivedPlayerProfileSectionProReviewData
{
    [self.playerProReviewTableView reloadData];
}
```

Why my protocol does not respond to selector?

Comment: Is `_playerProfileSectionProReviewDelegate` `nil`? Also, you probably want to define `playerProfileSectionProReviewDelegate` as a `weak` property.

Comment: Yes, `_playerProfileSectionProReviewDelegate` is `nil`! How to deal with it?

Comment: You have defined a `playerProfileSectionProReviewDelegate` property, but that's just a property. It's like the name of a variable - a shoebox. You have not given it any _value_. Unless you make some object _be_ this delegate, there is nobody there - the shoebox is empty (nil).

Comment: Hmmm... But then, how to initialise it?

    `_playerProfileSectionProReviewDelegate = [[PlayerProfileSectionProReviewDelegate alloc] init];`

?

Comment: You will see that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/626898/how-do-i-create-delegates-in-objective-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere in your `PlayerProfileSectionProReviewViewController` class implementation, you need to set the appropriate `PlayerProfileSectionProReviewModel` object's delegate, like this:

```
myModel.playerProfileSectionProReviewDelegate = self;
```

If you do this, then when `myModel` reaches your delegate call, your view controller will receive it.

By the way, you can simplify these lines:

```
if ([self.playerProfileSectionProReviewDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didReceivedPlayerProfileSectionProReviewData)])
{
    [self.playerProfileSectionProReviewDelegate didReceivedPlayerProfileSectionProReviewData];
}
```

With:

```
[self.playerProfileSectionProReviewDelegate didReceivedPlayerProfileSectionProReviewData];
```

At this point if the delegate is `nil`, no message will be sent and you won't get any runtime error.

Comment: Thank you very much! It was such a stupid mistake, that took me for such a long time!